# How to fix a badly setup svn repo

Tags: svn, branch, trunk

I have an svn repo that was setup (not by me) without the recommended folders (`/trunk`, `/branches`, `/tags`) which was fine initially, but we are running into problems that really should be fixed in a feature branch and pushed back to the trunk.

There is a remote branch on a webserver that pulls from svn to get its updates (so that we can also make changes there if there is an emergency and push back to the repo.

It would be nice if we could move all of the stuff that should be in the trunk into a `/trunk` folder, but I am wary to do that because of how I think it will affect the webserver's setup.

If I change the repo, and move all of the code into the proper folders, is there a way to repoint the remote version at the `/trunk` folder instead of `/`? (It would be nice if it pulled from `tags` instead of `trunk` but... baby steps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the webserver is acting as a client of the SVN server and doing updates to pull the latest version of the site, then after making the changes to the structure on the server, you would do:

```
svn switch --relocate SVN_URL/ SVN_URL/trunk
```

This would then update the checked out copy on the webserver to the new path and everything should continue along as normal.

Comment: Cool, that is exactly what I thought would work (didn't want to do it without at least a little confirmation...), but all the documentation that I found on `svn switch` seems to be about changing the location of the whole repo rather than just changing the folder that it is pulling from.

Comment: `svn switch` has two modes of operation. One is to switch amongst branches in the repository, which will cause versioned files to be updated.  The other, using the `--relocate` flag, is used to tell the working copy that the URL it is attached to has changed.  If can be used, as in this case, to deal with rearranging the repository. Or, it can be used when the whole repository is moved, such as from one server to another, or if the server name changes.